# How do I know when the 'unqiue' validation rule breaks when sending a JSON POST request?

Tags: laravel

From what I know, Laravel will response with a 422 when validation fails for any rule.

What if I am only interested in certain rule failures, like the 'unique'? 
How do I check that a certain input field fails the validation because of the 'unique' rule?

Comment: u can share with us ur controller and model code please !

Answer (score 0):

You still get all the validation errors, as far as you're sending the correct headers - which you are, otherwise you wouldn't get `422`.

Then the validation errors are returned in this format:

```
{
    errors: {
        field1: ["Field 1 must be unique", /* other failures */],
        // ... other fields
    },
    message: "The given data was invalid"
}
```

The error code `422` is correct (returned by Laravel's validation failure) and indicates that there was, in fact, an error.

You just need to call `response.data` on your response object in JavaScript to access the returned data (at least with Axios).

Answer (score 0):

you can check returning json parameters in your js codes easily but if you want customizing response there is a way to manipulate responses if you are validating fields in your laravel controllers.

Check for a specific rule within the returned array of failed rules in your controller:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {

   $failedRules = $validator->failed();

   if(isset($failedRules['email_address']['Unique'])) {

   ...
```

in this way you find specifically failure(in this example email address must be Unique) and do your own action and return response.